# Calling WebService from Ajax/Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services

I am getting into a little jam here. I created a webservice using C#. When I Invoke the WebService it works fine. The Javascript seems to be hitting the webservice, breaking, and then follows through with the rest of the operation. I think this is a matter of me calling the WebService wrong. I've searched all over and have found tons of different examples, however, none of them seem to work.

If you go to http://success.darkslidedesign.com it triggers test.js which then calls my web service located here: http://www.darkslidedesign.com/services/ms_Alert.asmx

Here is the test.js code -

```
var xmlHttp;
setTimeout("sendMessage('rory@careercheatcode.com');", 2000);
function doUpdate()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState===4){
        alert("Worked");
        }
    else{
        alert("Broke");
        }
}
function sendMessage(strTo)
{
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Ajax is not supported
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }   
    xmlHttp.open("post", "http://www.darkslidedesign.com/services/ms_Alert.asmx", true);    
    var params = "op=Sending_Email&strEmailAddrFrom=rory@darkslidedesign.com&strEmailAddrTo=" + strTo;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");    
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=doUpdate;    
    xmlHttp.send(params);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using jQuery's extensive yet light AJAX library for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Getting a readystate != 4 doesn't mean that it broke; it just means that the request isn't finished loading yet.  Also, try using two equal signs instead of three.

Comment: @lazycs: Typically in javascript, you should always use 3 equal signs for testing equality. Otherwise you can end up with unexpected results due to type coercion.

Comment: @lazycs - I know it doesn't break it. It's dummy text.

Comment: Please note that the problem is not with the DoUpdate function. My problem lies somewhere in the following code. I need to have it setup this way because the client can only inclue one javascript file to the page (pointed at test.js) and that should handle the rest.

Comment: xmlHttp.open("post", "http://www.darkslidedesign.com/services/ms_Alert.asmx", true);    
    var params = "op=Sending_Email&strEmailAddrFrom=rory@darkslidedesign.com&strEmailAddrTo=" + strTo;
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");    
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=doUpdate;    
    xmlHttp.send(params);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better start with jQuery $.ajax()
Here is one snippet that works for me to post comment from a textbox.

```
function Post() {
         var ow = "username";
         var cmt = $("#comment").val();
         $.ajax(
         {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/comment/Save",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id=2332&author=" + ow + "&cmt=" + cmt,
            success: function (result) {
               if (result.status === "OK") {
                  alert('Comment posted');
               }
               else
                  alert("Post failed");
            },

            error: function (req, status, error) {
               alert("Sorry! Post failed due to error");
            }
         });

      }
```

Hope this will guide you.
Thanks

Comment: comment is the id of the textbox. you need to specify the url to which you are posting to

Answer (score -1):

For web service calls from Javascript, I use two things:

1. jQuery, as **pixelbobby** mentioned. It is a walk in the park and makes everything super awesome-sauce!
2. I use the asp.net MVC framework. It is far too verbose for me to explain it here, but it is pretty easy to get it up and running. Basically, you create a controller class, create some methods, and return json-serialized values. You might also have to add some routes to your global.asax file.

I would definately recommend reading up on both of these things... They are both pretty awesome!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. However, I need it to be triggered off a single call to a javascript file, for ease on a client. That will then trigger the Web Service that does the rest. The problem is towards the end of the sendUpdate function, I believe, with the XMLHttp object.